# Git push does not trigger CI/CD pipeline on GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm running a self-hosted GitLab v14.9.1 and for some reason using `git push` does not trigger any pipeline.

In case if I update any file directly into the GitLab GUI then pipeline is starting without problem. Thus maybe someone knows a workaround of this.

Here below is the .gitlab-ci.yaml file which I created for test purposes (but still having the same issue).

```
stages:
  - deploy

pipe:
  stage: deploy
  #when: manual
  image:
    name: alpine
  script:
    - echo "something"
```

Comment: Can you please add your `gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Comment: As I said currently I'm using simple test yaml:

stages:
  - deploy

pipe:
  stage: deploy
  #when: manual
  image:
    name: alpine
  script:
    - echo "something"
  only:
    - main